# How to correctly store data of type date in MongoDB?

Tags: laravel, mongodb

I'm using Laravel with MongoDB and I have a data processing problem. My `start` and `end` fields are receiving data of type string, but I would like them to stay of type date.

```
public function store(PersonRequest $request)
{
    $validations = $request->validated();

    $treated_data = [
      'begin' => $validations['begin'],
      'end' => $validations['end'],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a thread on the MongoDB site about [Working with datetime as string](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/working-with-datetime-as-string/7296)
it would appear you can store dates as strings as long as they are correctly formatted.

Parse the date using [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) and store the ISO formatted output:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

    ...

    $treated_data = [
      'begin' => Carbon::parse($validations['begin'])->toIso8601String(),
      ...
    ];
```

Be aware that `parse()` will return the current date and time if `null` is given to it. Use `make()` if you want to keep the `null` value. If parsing fails, both function throw an exception. However, if you have correctly validated the input this should not be a problem.

An alternative approach would be to use an Eloquent model for your entity as dates can be automatically cast when reading or writing your documents.

If you make the model's properties fillable you can create a new object directly from the validate request data.